# Python 2.7.2 - Cannot import name _random or random from sys

Tags: python, random

Im a few months new to Python and am pulling my hair out over trying to simply generate a random integer.  Ive been scouring the internet, tried many solutions provided on here but nothing takes. Python just doesnt seem to know it has a random module, though i can see it right there in my lib.  What ive tried:

- copied it relative to my .py doc and did an import random without the sys and get the same error.
- In the interactive help i found the "_random", so import _random doesn't give me a line 1 error,  but says my random is not defined even though ive copied and pasted numerous random number code examples straight from python help and many from this site that stated worked properly for them.

about to throw in the towel

tried to post a pic but apparently not "reputable" enough. The exact error is:

```
Macintosh:week 03a ersander$ python SecretDoor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SecretDoor.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sys import _random
ImportError: cannot import name _random
```

Comment: `from random import randint`?

Answer (score 9):

```
import random
```

`random` isn't in `sys`. I don't know why you're trying to import it from there.

Comment: This answer is correct, but just because I am curious, I'll point this out: 

`dir(sys)` does not show an attributed called `_random`, however, `sys.__dict__` does have a key named `_random`.  You cannot import it and when you try `print sys._random` you will get `AttributeError: 'module' object has not attribute '_random'`.  This seems a little weird to me and I'm unsure what is going on.

Comment: @Vorticity: `sys.__dict__['_random']` gives a KeyError for me, on Python 2.7.3.

Comment: Hmmm...does for me too.  However, if I do `print sys.__dict__` I see this in the result: `'_random': <module '_random' from '/opt/python-2.7.1/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_random.so'>,`.

Comment: That's `sys.modules['_random']`.

Comment: Ugh, apparently this is a day for facepalms.  I'll use the fact that this is my Monday as an excuse.

Comment: i only added the "from sys" as an attempt after simply "import random" came back with ImportErrors - specifically ones i named below "ImportError: No module named python"

Comment: @EricSanderson: You probably had a file named something like `random.py` with weird stuff in it. One of the places Python looks for modules to import is the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint
print(randint(0, 100))
```

Is this what you're looking for?
Try Googling along the lines of (first hit): [python random integer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint)

Comment: ya i actually found and tried that, i get back: ImportError No Module names python.  Im guessing its just not looking in the right place for random?

Comment: `No Module named python`? what does `import random` and `print random.name` say?

Comment: UPDATE:  That code seems to work when running python directly in terminal, but not as a .py doc saved out of my editor.

Comment: interesting.  i deleted the extra "random" modules i saved relative to my doc path and now the "from random import randint" seems to go through, now just running into the next problem i keep hitting, being 'randint' is not defined. (and thats happened with about every random generator ive tried). Straight up copied and pasted your code.  Thanks a ton for the help thus far btw.  Komodo Edit 8

Comment: @EricSanderson Try executing your script with: `python -m trace --trace test.py` and see what it tries to import/run.

Comment: Btw, `from random import randint` is a **native** python module, you shouldn't need to download/try any other modules.

Comment: Ya thats what i originally thought and tried, lets just say i exhausted many paths before posting on here lol.

Comment: Humm, after doing `import random` and when it works, can you do `print  random` and a `print random.randint`? (Hehe, you i tend to do the same and end up in a bigger shithole then i started out with :P) It should give you `<module 'random' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/random.pyc'>` (and btw, what gave "command not found"?)

Comment: <module 'random' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.pyc'>
<bound method Random.randint of <random.Random object at 0x7fd6cc05f020>>   Path to my lib's seem a bit extensive.

Comment: running the python -m trace --trace (my file).py gave me command not found. and test.py gave me invalid syntax

Comment: Shit something is really up with your installation that's for sure, which OS?

Comment: success!! for whatever reason, i copied and pasted your original code again, and it worked from my editor this time.  Not sure what running any of those previous scripts did, but obviously something.

Comment: I'm glad it's working :P (I was about to tell you to reinstall your Python) :)

Comment: OS 10.8.2  glad its working now, not very comfortable not knowing why. Thanks for hanging in there with me

Comment: A shit you're rocking on a MAC (I've done some projects on those and let me tell you, you're better off not knowing how much crap it caches in the middle layers of the I/O operations and how much it can cause you trouble.. be happy it's working :P) And you're welcome, gl with your endeavors!